# Erro na formação de uma string através de um Loop (com Foreach) em um Array

Tags: php, mysql

Olá.

Eu tenho um código que faz um Foreach em um Array que forma uma String (em uma variável) com todos os valores desse Array.

O problema é que quando eu dou um echo essa String, no final do Loop, não é exibido algum valor. O echo dá uma saída vazia.

Porém, seu eu tirar os "<" e ">", a String é exibida normalmente. com os valores de todos os índices do Array.

**Vou deixar meu código:**

```html
<?php

//CLASSE PARA PEGAR TODOS OS USUÁRIOS QUE NÃO FOREM DE DESENVOLVIMENTO
 class PegarFuncionarios
 {    
  private $dep; 
  
  public function __get($atributo)
  {   
   return $this->$atributo;
  }
  
  public function __set($atributo, $valor)
  {   
   $this->$atributo = $valor;
  }  
       
  public function todosFuncionarios()
  { 
   try
   {   
    //Conexão com o Banco de Dados (Futuramente podemos atribuir essa conexao a uma classe
    $d = new Conexao();
    $conexao = $d->conectar();
        
    $query = "SELECT usuario FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE departamento <> :dep ORDER BY usuario";
    
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':dep',$this->__get('dep'));
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $lista_usuarios = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    
    //$retorno_usuarios = array();
    
    $retorno_usuarios = "";
    
    foreach($lista_usuarios as $key => $linha_usuarios)
    {  
     $retorno_usuarios .= "<". $linha_usuarios['usuario'] .">";      
    }       
    
    echo $retorno_usuarios;
    
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
    //Verificando o erro ocorrido
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();    
   }
  }  
 }
  
  
?>
```

**Sem o PDO**, em outra parte do sistema, eu faço um código parecido e dá certo (O problema é que agora eu estou querendo utilizar PDO com OO nos códigos. Para ficar melhor organizado e seguro). **Veja abaixo o código que dá certo com mysqli:**

```html
<?php

$pesquisar_interessados = "SELECT usuario FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE (administrador = 1 AND USUARIO <> '$usuario_logado') OR (DEPARTAMENTO = '$usuario_departamento' AND USUARIO <> '$usuario_logado' AND SUPERVISOR = 1)";
   $operacao_interessados = mysqli_query($conecta, $pesquisar_interessados) or die("Erro no Select interessados"); 
     
   $resultado = "";
   
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($operacao_interessados))
   {     
    $resultado .= "<".$row['usuario'].">";   
   }  




?>
```

Vocês saberiam dizer onde estou errando ? Parece ser um erro bem básico.

Comment: Fiz algo de errado na formulação da pergunta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thiago, ele está pensando que < é uma tag html.  Ao invés de usar "<", use `"&#60;"` e ao invés de ">", use `"&#62;"` e veja se resolve.
Porque `<qualquer_coisa>` é uma tag.
O navegador detecta automaticamente o header, ele pode reconhecer um como html e outro como plaintext.
Todavia, você não deve usar caracteres especiais como < assim mesmo, então troque pelos respectivos entities

Comment: Obrigado, Denied. Funcionou. Queria só saber por que em um código funcionou e no outro teve que fazer isso que vocÊ falou.